# navbar fixed Position offset scroll and smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm having a problem, I have two js scripts that doesn't work together.

The first one makes a "scroll to ID" with an offset so it matches the height of the fixed navbar on top of the browser.

The second one is for making the scroll smooth as it travels, so it doesn't just instantly go to the target ID. The problem is I can't merge them together.

**Scroll with offset:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".first-scroller").on('click', 'a', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var o = $($(this).attr("href")).offset();
        var sT = o.top - $("#fixedbar").outerHeight(true);
        window.scrollTo(0, sT);
    });
});
```

**Smooth scroll:**

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {

    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');

        if (target.length) {

            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);

            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like you could get rid of the first function as just paste `- $("#fixedbar").outerHeight(true)` after `scrollTop: target.offset().top` in the second one. Wrap it in a doc ready function of course.

Comment: can u write the code please, Tryed doing that and its not working, dunno if  I have to add Coma or something, my Javascript is bad :(

Comment: Easy peasy : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mewvNv?editors=001